# How can I change whether the Enter key runs code or accepts an autocomplete suggestion in the Chrome Devtools console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When I type into console and there is a list of suggestions, if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the first option is selected. I want pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to just run the code as it is and the suggestions to be inserted only if I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome DevTools 113, there is a new setting under the "Console" section called "Accept autocomplete suggestion on Enter". It seems (at least for me) that the default value is "off" (unchecked).

See here for the announcement and more details: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-113/?utm_source=devtools#console.

If you are using a version of Chrome DevTools older than 113, then the workaround is to close the autocomplete popup by pressing <kbd>escape</kbd> before pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, or to toggle autocompletion entirely, which you can do by unchecking "Autocomplete" under the "Sources" section of the settings (of course, the problem then is that if you want to disable the Enter key for autocomplete, you will have no autocomplete at all). Note that in older versions of Chrome, this might not have any effect in the console, and instead only affect the "Sources" tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn of Autocompletion in the Dev Tools settings.
However, it is only possible for the **`Sources` tab** and **not for the console**
(go to `Sources` and check of the box `Autocompletion`).

What worked for me was starting the habit of **always ending a line with `;`** before pressing Enter.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I dream of finding a solution without extra presses :(

Comment: > ending a line with `;`
Thanks for the tip!  Unfortunately can't use that in all cases e.g. modifying an argument in a function; typing `null` in `console.log(null)` and pressing enter results in output of `console.log(isNull)`.  This is just an over-zealous feature of chrome dev tools.  I wonder if there's a bug report on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the autocomplete by pressing arrow left, or Esc.

Very annoying, I have for habit to press right, but that only selects the autocomplete. Like 30 times and my habit persists. Maybe I will learn it now.